# how to solve a TypeError error in rails 4 in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form to create vehicals and define the route corresponding to it, But it consistently gives a TypeError error, I think I am doing it wrong, please correct following is the code:

```
<%= form_for @vehical, url_for(:action => :create, :controller => 'vehicals') do |vehical| %>
<div>
<%= vehical.label 'house power'%>
  <%= vehical.text_field 'horse_power'%>
</div>
    <div>
      <%= vehical.label 'brand' %>
      <%= vehical.text_field 'brand' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= vehical.label 'model' %>
      <%= vehical.text_field 'model' %>
    </div>

    <%= vehical.submit 'create' %>
<% end %>
```

routes for it:

```
 match '/vehicals/create', :to => 'vehicals#create', :as => 'vehicals_create', :via => :post
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
    1: 
    2: <%= form_for @vehical, url_for(:action => :create, :controller => 'vehicals') do |vehical| %>
    3: <div>
    4: <%= vehical.label 'house power'%>
    5:   <%= vehical.text_field 'horse_power'%>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a symbol for the action value. You need a string:

```
url_for(action: 'create', controller: 'vehicals')
```

You could also do this, but you may have to tweak the route helper if you don't have that route set up:

```
form_for @vehical, create_vehicle_path, method: :post
```